# How to check template parameterized callback function signature is a kind of

Tags: c++, c++11

In a flow I set a templated callback function like below:

`otherobju_ptr->Req(std::bind(&A::test<uint16_t>,this,std::placeholders::_1), id);`

Now before invoking the callback I need to validate if the callback is of valid signature type:

```
class otherobj  
{
public:
    using CallbackType = std::function<void(const bool&)>;
    int Reg( CallbackType callback, uint32_t& id)
    {
         //Need to check if the function template parameter is correct
          // Trying the below way but not sure where we can give the template parameter <bool>
           static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<decltype(callback), std::function<void(const bool&)>>, "Wrong Callback function");
    }
};
```

I am not able to find the solution as is make the signature like below:

```
 static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<decltype(callback), std::function<void<bool>(const bool&)>>, "Wrong Signature!");
```

It errors out - is there a way we can validate the template arguments type of a std::function callback?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If the callback doesn't match the signature then any use of `Reg` will fail to compile.

Comment: What is `A`? What is `test`? What is `var` in this example? if you want to check that var is `uint16_t` then declare `using CallbackType = std::function<void(const uint16 &)>;` without any additional checks

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue - I have update the question with correct type of argument var

Comment: But you are still using `var` in other places... However now these checks make even less sense because you already know the exact type of `CallbackType `

Comment: Thanks again - I have update the question

Comment: @FantasticMrFox - The signature of the function includes a template parameter and compiles if we pass any type in this example it is <uint16_t>

Comment: @VTT - I am registering class A test function that is template - in my case I need instance with type <uint16_t> type

Comment: you might want to use `static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<CallbackType, const bool&>)`

Comment: Alright, you are instantiating it with `uint16_t` when creating a callback object... Type of callback is `std::function<void(const bool&)>`, nothing else, there is no way to figure out what kind of callable thing is kept inside of wrapper. And there is no need to because `std::function` is used when you want to hide those details. Anyway, without [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is not going anywhere...

Comment: @VTT - thanks I understand - however in std::function type variable how can we add template parameter type as in its signature - is there a way?

Comment: Template parameters are not part of function signatures. And it is still not clear what are you really trying to achieve here...

Comment: @VTT - the aim is that I allow only a specific type function signature with its parameter type instance - if in case the function signature is incorrect need to throw error at compilation time

Comment: If function signature is not correct (that is not `void(const bool&)` as written in your example) then compiler will issue an error without any additional checks.

Comment: @VTT - I understand that but the caller will provide a template parameterized callback - std::bind(&A::test<uint16_t>,this,std::placeholders::_1)....) - so I need to check the parameter type provided before invoking the function using the callback arguments

Comment: By wrapping callback into `std::function` you are hiding that `&A::test<uint16_t>` will be invoked. If you want to inspect it later then you are doing something wrong (either attempt to inspect is wrong or use of std::function to hide callable details is wrong).

Comment: @VTT - thanks is there some other way to achieve that objective?

Comment: @Programmer Let me explain this way: Your `Reg` function is a car mechanic. The caller is a customer who brings cars (of a certain car brand = call signature). The compiler is the security guy at the entrance to the shop and only lets in that exact car brand. As far as we can tell, you are currently asking "how can I make sure the security guy lets in blue cars only if they are the brand I service?" (where color = template argument). And we keep trying to tell you "1. you don't have to do that because if it's not the correct brand (= signature) it's not getting past security, and...

Comment: ... 2. why do you even care about the color (or whether the car has a color at all)?". The sign at the front of your shop says "repairing all cars of brand X" and that's what you do. Why do you want another security guy that checks that the car would still be the same brand if you paint it blue?

Comment: And no, there is no way to add a template parameter to `std::function`'s type signature. Because there is no need to do that. `std::function` says "here is something you can call with this signature". It is the job of the caller of your function to satisfy that, not yours. Once you have a `std::function<void(bool)>` (as you do in `Reg`), it is guaranteed that you can call it that way. You cannot (and should not, and need not) apply template parameters after that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Thanks for the detailed description - I understand your viewpoint . I agree completely with you that it is the job of the caller to certify its type - not that the calle should worry about